# Problem with arrows between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, node-connections

I need to draw an arrow between 2 nodes but not from the center of the node. When I use a position modificator a new arrow end appears at the starting point.

This is a minimal example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [column sep=1cm,row sep=3cm]{
    \node [] (node1) {Node 1}; \\
    \node [] (node2) {Node 2}; \\
  };

  \begin{scope}[every path/.style={draw, thick,-latex',shorten >= 2pt}]
    \path[bend right] (node1) edge (node2);
    \path[bend right] (node1.south) edge (node2);
    \path[bend right] (node1.south east) edge (node2);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Example]

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `every edge/.style` instead of the `every path/.style`:

```
\begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw, thick,-latex',shorten >= 2pt}]
```

With this modification to your code I get the desired result:

[image]